# How to use subscriber status in a filtered group

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters

I am trying to update a filtered group, which is filtered on "All Subscribers". I want to exclude subscribers with status "Unsubscribed" from All Subscribers which cant be selected in the filter, when creating the group.

The goal is to have a filtered group with subscribers that is "Active"

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

As far as i know, it can be done by creating a measure, but i am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is this a Marketing Cloud question? You might add some relevant tags or description to clarify - it's pretty opaque to non-MC Salesforce users like me.

Comment: Yes this is a Marketing Cloud Question. Is this the wrong forum?

Comment: Not at all! Just not everyone here knows or can immediately recognize MC content, so tagging can help attract the users who do have that expertise and let the rest of us know what's up.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write a SQL query on the [_Subscriber data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) or you can use [_ListSubscribers using the ListID](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) in a `WHERE` clause.